# Why was this question deleted?(reverse engineering wmd editor)

Tags: support, stack-overflow, deleted-questions, blog

Hello, I recently went searching meta for a question about the markdown engine and stumbled upon a question instead about the markdown editor. I read into it and wound up at the blog: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/

In that blog post is this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406132/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor  which yields a 404 on stackoverflow.

I can't quite imagine why such a question would be deleted. So why was it?

Comment: It's a bit meta, isn't it?  Jeff Atwood says in one of the answers that it was only moved to SO to get greater exposure.  But it is, in fact, "Not a Real Question."

Comment: @Rob I'm not 10k, so I couldn't read the question's text. Even if it wasn't a real question, why not have it undeleted and closed instead?

Comment: Closing a question really means it's eventually deleted.  There is a two day grace period between the time a question is closed and it is voted for deletion, but that's what it amounts to.  This particular question was closed by a moderator, but it was deleted by community vote.  The deletion message reads: `deleted by SilentGhost, bmargulies, Roger Pate May 20 '10 at 19:18`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a convenient discussion and wiki spot for reverse engineering the markdown engine since the author wasn't easy to contact.

It served its purpose, and is now only available to 10k+ reputation users as a historical artifact, but is not of any use to the programming community at large and thus doesn't belong on SO.